# How does Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D cross over with Captain America 2?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, agents-of-shield, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

As the majority of people will be aware, *Captain America 2* features S.H.I.E.L.D. working against the Winter Soldier, and S.H.I.E.L.D is in a much better state than in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. How does this work out?

For example, the majority of S.H.I.E.L.D transports, bases and agents

> were stolen or were actually Hydra in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.;

yet in Captain America 2 it doesn't seem S.H.I.E.L.D. is fighting a war from the inside, unlike in the series. How is this possible?

I have not watched the movie myself but I have seen all episodes of AoS; so please forgive me if I am wrong (a friend told me about CA2).

Comment: You're actually quite wrong about Captain America 2, as the movie was actually the *reason* the TV Show went in that direction.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I seem to remember Coulsons team making the discovery independent of Steve Rogers Triskellion speech though. I would have said that both the TV show and the film were affected by in-universe events, not neccesarily that one caused the other.

Comment: @DrRDizzle In an interview somewhere the writers said that "Centipede", from the very first episode, was a code-name for _the spoilered thing_, because they knew where everything was going but weren't allowed to say _the spoilered thing_ until the movie came out

Comment: @DrRDizzle I was speaking out-of-universe, sorry about that. The writers for *Winter Soldier* had their plot twist planned out before the writers for the SHIELD TV show got started, so the TV writers knew well in advanced what was going to happen and had to write around it.

Comment: How does *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* cross over with *Captain America 2*? Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* take place during the the same time period as an episode of *Agents of SHIELD*, when it is revealed that

> Hydra have infiltrated SHIELD from the inside.

*Captain America: The Winter Soldier* deals with the discovery of this information from Steve Roger's perspective and how he goes about exposing it, whereas *Agents of SHIELD* has an episode dedicated to Coulson and his team learning about it.

Every episode since the reveal in *Agents of SHIELD* has occurred *after* the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.

Comment: There's even a throwaway line during the _Agents of SHIELD_ episode that references the movie happening concurrently

Comment: @Izkata it's not even all that throwaway... there are at least two major characters from the movie that end up re-appearing on the show with references to their disposition at the end of *Winter Soldier*.

Answer (score 12):

The first season of *Agents of SHIELD* was being broadcast at the same time as the US release of *The Winter Soldier*. Events occurred semi-concurrently.

At the end of *Winter Soldier*, it was revealed that:

> HYDRA had infiltrated SHIELD, and the Winter Soldier was working with/for them. The film ends with the Triskelion (SHIELD headquarters) essentially destroyed, SHIELD discredited, and HYDRA running amuck.

The US release of *Winter Soldier* was 4th April, and the next episode of *AoS* was broadcast on 8th April. This was *Turn, Turn, Turn*, which is the first time the *AoS* cast learnt about the events of *Winter Soldier*.

*AoS* then ran for five more episodes, developing this plot line much further. In the show, some time has passed since the end of *Winter Soldier*, and so SHIELD is in a more dire state.